# Spring Data Neo4j Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound; Description: Unable to load NODE with id

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Neo4j schema:

[image]

I'm trying to delete a nodes with a following `SDN 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` Repository with Cypher query:

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[:COMMENTED_ON*]-(com:Comment) DETACH DELETE com WITH d OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c) WITH d, c OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg) WITH d, c, vg OPTIONAL MATCH (vg)-[:CONTAINS]->(v) DETACH DELETE v, vg, c, d")
void deleteDecisions(@Param("decisionsIds") List<Long> decisionsIds);
```

Right now I'm getting a following exception after this method execution:

```
org.neo4j.ogm.exception.CypherException: Error executing Cypher; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound; Description: Unable to load NODE with id 2157.
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.executeRequest(EmbeddedRequest.java:176)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.embedded.request.EmbeddedRequest.execute(EmbeddedRequest.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:93)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.ExecuteQueriesDelegate.query(ExecuteQueriesDelegate.java:73)
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.query(Neo4jSession.java:313)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.deleteDecisions(Unknown Source)
```

where NODE with id `2157` is a `VoteGroup` entity.

This is my entities:

```
@NodeEntity
public class VoteGroup extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String VOTED_ON = "VOTED_ON";
    private final static String VOTED_FOR = "VOTED_FOR";
    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @Relationship(type = VOTED_FOR, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Decision decision;

    @Relationship(type = VOTED_ON, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Criterion criterion;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Vote> votes = new HashSet<>();

    private double avgVotesWeight;

    private long totalVotesCount;

    public VoteGroup() {
    }

    public VoteGroup(Decision decision, Criterion criterion, double avgVotesWeight, long totalVotesCount) {
        this.decision = decision;
        decision.addVoteGroup(this);
        this.criterion = criterion;
        criterion.addVoteGroup(this);
        this.avgVotesWeight = avgVotesWeight;
        this.totalVotesCount = totalVotesCount;
    }
...
}

@NodeEntity
public class Vote extends Authorable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private VoteGroup group;

    private double weight;

    private String description;

    public Vote() {
    }

    public Vote(VoteGroup group, User author, double weight, String description) {
        this.group = group;
        group.addVote(this);
        setAuthor(author);
        this.weight = weight;
        this.description = description;
    }
...
}
```

What is wrong with my query ?

**UPDATED**

I have tried this also at Standalone Neo4j Server with the same results:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Neo4j issue, please log it at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues with your query, EXPLAIN plan and error message.

In the meanwhile, if you drop the early delete for comments and do them all at the end, you should be able to move ahead:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN [155, 163, 144]  
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[:COMMENTED_ON*]-(com:Comment) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(c) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)<-[:VOTED_ON]-(vg) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (vg)-[:CONTAINS]->(v) 
DETACH DELETE v, vg, c, d,com
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem which was due to the 
"neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver" version I used in my pom.
I accidently overwrote the version "spring-data-neo4j" 
used by default (2.0.3) with 2.0.5. And this lead to 
the described problem ..